# How to split contained words string to to function parameters in BASH?

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments

Example code

```
input="cp directory_a directory_b" # obtaining value from keyboard

eval_input $input
```

I hope `$input` can be splitted into `$0`, `$1` and `$2` in `eval_input` function. So far i use this method to archive it

```
eval_input $(echo $input)
```

But i think maybe there is more better way.

**Note that** `$input` here, in actually it suppose to be obtained its value from a user not assign by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting strings in shell leads to many difficult problems.  The best solution is not to create a string.  Use an array:

```
input=(cp directory_a directory_b)
eval_input "${input[@]}"
```

This provides `cp`, `directory_a` and  `directory_b` as the arguments to `eval_input` which eval_input can reference as `$1,`$2`, and`$3`.

This approach will work even if some of the command's arguments contain spaces or other difficult characters.  For example, the following will work well:

```
input=(cp "directory a" "directory b")
```

Trying to do that using a string instead of array will be very difficult.

#### Using a user-supplied string

You can use the `read` command to break user-supplied input into individual arguments:

```
$ input="cp directory_a directory_b"
$ read -a array <<<"$input"
```

You can verify that the above succeeded by examining the output of `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="cp" [1]="directory_a" [2]="directory_b")'
```

You can access individual elements of `array` as follows:

```
$ echo "${array[0]}"
cp
$ echo "${array[1]}"
directory_a
```

Comment: Please check my note that i just added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set --` to set positional parameters:

```
( input="cp directory_a directory_b"; set -- $input; echo "[$1] [$2] [$3]"; )
```

**Output:**

```
[cp] [directory_a] [directory_b]
```

PS: Use `(...)` to avoid messing up current shell and do this in a sub-shell.

Comment: This approach has the advantage of POSIX compatibility. +1